# Promise takes 15 seconds to run "then" function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bluebird

```
Promise.resolve(true).then(function(){console.log("run");});
```

This code takes 15-16 seconds to return "run" to the console.

Versions:

- Chrome 46.0.2466.0 canary (64-bit) (works fine in Version 44.0.2403.107 (64-bit))
- bluebird@2.9.34
- browserify@11.0.0

I am running it in a script that is included in a chrome extension background page (loaded via a `<script>` tag).

The script is build with browserify, and bluebird is included via:

```
Promise = require('bluebird')
```

I think there is a problem with the difference in how the chrome/node environments manage timeouts?

Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chromium 46.0.2464.0 on Linux (x64), I did: 1) `npm install bluebird@2.9.34 browserify@11.0.0` 2) `echo -e 'var Promise = require('bluebird');\nPromise.resolve(true).then(function(){console.log("run");});' > main.js` 3) `./node_modules/.bin/browserify main.js -o background.js` 4) Loaded a Chrome extension using this background.js in Chromium (44.0.2403.89 and 46.0.2464.0). Observed result: "run" is immediately printed.

Comment: Is there other code running right after this line?  You will have two delays before seeing it in the console.  The first delay is because the `.then()` handler is forced to be async so it will not run until all other code in this thread of execution has finished running.  The second delay will be just the inherent delays in seeing things show up in the console (which should not be 15 seconds, but is often not instantaneous).  Please provide a reproducible case in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Hey @RobW thanks for testing this out. I tried to replicate after restarting my machine and recompiling my code and it worked fine. Im not sure what was causing it.